# is cork underlayment on a concrete basement floor a workable proposition?

Tags: basement, flooring, underlayment, cork

Next up in my basement finish process are the floors. We've decided to go with vinyl for the bathroom (and under-stairs closet), and carpet everywhere else.

I'm planning on putting in a 6mil plastic vapor barrier first, then gluing 1/4" cork underlayment on, and finally installing the flooring choices.

Is this a safe thing to do in the basement? For what it's worth, we've been here since new in 2008, and haven't ever seen any sort of water issues in the basement. The floor is bare concrete at the moment, with a few carpet remnants scattered around.

If this won't work, please provide alternate suggestions on how I can incorporate cork underlayment... something about its thermal properties is extremely appealing, and I can't think of another product that can do this at an equivalent cost.